# Kubernetes 1.11 could not find heapster for metrics

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, kubectl, sys, system-administration

I'm using Kubernetes 1.11 on Digital Ocean, when I try to use kubectl top node I get this error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)
```

but as stated in the doc, heapster is deprecated and no longer required from kubernetes 1.10

Comment: Seems to be a present issue:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46915

Comment: What does 'kubectl get ns' say?

Comment: What does 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces' report?

Answer (score 19):

If you are running a newer version of Kubernetes and still receiving this error, there is probably a problem with your installation.

Please note that to install metrics server on kubernetes, you should first clone it by typing:

```
git clone https://github.com/kodekloudhub/kubernetes-metrics-server.git
```

then you should install it, **WITHOUT GOING INTO THE CREATED FOLDER AND WITHOUT MENTIONING AN SPECIFIC YAML FILE** , only via:

```
kubectl create -f kubernetes-metrics-server/
```

In this way all services and components are installed correctly and you can run:

```
kubectl top nodes
```

or

```
kubectl top pods
```

and get the correct result.

Answer (score 13):

For `kubectl top node/pod` to work you either need the [heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) or the [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) installed on your cluster.

Like the warning says: *heapster* is being deprecated so the recommended choice now is the *metrics server*.

So follow the directions [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) to install the metrics server

Comment: I installed metrics-server in the cluster in the kube-system namespace, but still getting the same error. if I do kubectl logs kubectl logs metrics-server-85dc785fbf-76qf9 I get this output

`E1018 12:10:51.797774       1 manager.go:102] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:nostalgic-pare-gt8: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet nostalgic-pare-gt8 (nostalgic-pare-gt8): Get https://nostalgic-pare-gt8:10250/stats/summary/: dial tcp: lookup nostalgic-pare-gt8 on 10.245.0.10:53: no such host`

Comment: @FakeAccount Use this argument for metrics-server: --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,InternalDNS,ExternalIP,ExternalDNS

Comment: I have kube-state-metrics still I get admin@ip-172-21-59-122:~$ kubectl top nodes
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)
admin@ip-172-21-59-122:~$ kubectl top nodes  -n kube-system
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource (get services http:heapster:)